# Periodically change imageview background and smooth android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image, android-handler

I have an `ImageView` and 16 images. I want to change the background image according to these images. I used `Handler` but the result is not changing smoothly. How can I make the changing more smooth? Do you think `AnimationDrawable` is better? This is my code

```
private static int[] drawable_img_Array = { R.drawable.img01, R.drawable.img02,R.drawable.img03,R.drawable.img04,
        R.drawable.img05, R.drawable.img06,R.drawable.img07,R.drawable.img08,
        R.drawable.img09, R.drawable.img10,R.drawable.img11,R.drawable.img12,
        R.drawable.img13, R.drawable.img14,R.drawable.img15};

final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            if(i<drawable_img_Array.length) {
                imgView.setImageResource(drawable_img_Array[i]);
                i++;
            } else {
                i=0;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }, 100);
```

This is my second way using AnimationDrawable

```
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();

    for (int j=0;j<drawable_ring_Array.length;j++)
    {
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(drawable_img_Array[j]), 100);

    }
    animation.setOneShot(false);
    ImageView imgView = (imgView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400);
    params.alignWithParent = true;
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    imgView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(animation);
    imgView.post(new Starter());
```

Comment: Have you tried the `ImageSwitcher` ? Maybe it will serve for your purpose. Take a look this links: [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) and [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm)

Comment: What does it mean "the result is not changing smoothly"? Is there any performance issue or you just want to change the view's resource with animation?

Comment: Just want to change the view's resource with animation and reduce delay. The delay makes the changing is not smooth. I think delay is from loading image in the loop

Answer (score 2):

There are some logical error in your code. That are as follows :

Firstly Your else portion will not work as expected.
it should be like this :

```
} else {
   i=0;
   imgView.setImageResource(drawable_img_Array[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Finally that could be the real problem run code on UI thread like that

```
private static int[] drawable_img_Array = {R.drawable.img01,
            R.drawable.img02, R.drawable.img03, R.drawable.img04,
            R.drawable.img05, R.drawable.img06, R.drawable.img07, R.drawable.img08,
            R.drawable.img09, R.drawable.img10, R.drawable.img11, R.drawable.img12,
            R.drawable.img13, R.drawable.img14, R.drawable.img15};

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (i < drawable_img_Array.length) {
                        imgView.setImageResource(drawable_img_Array[i]);
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        i=0;
                        imgView.setImageResource(drawable_img_Array[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            });
        }
    }
            , 100);
```

Hope it whould work if not than post the log/error so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ImageSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html)

```
<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/image_switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in_image"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out_image">
</ImageSwitcher>
```

you can create any animations you want and use them for in/out.

Now when calling `imageSwitcher.setImageResource(myNextImage)` it'll animate the transition.